# Android - how service can retrieve path from opened file

Tags: android, file, android-intent, path, android-service

I create a service that when I click a button **should retrieve the path of the current open document** (.png/.doc/.txt) how to do it? 
Knowing that **I do not open the file directly from my application**, I need to retrieve this path even if **the user opens a document from another file explorer**

or

There is a way to know **all open files** and get their path as quickly as possible ??

or get latest opened file ? if we consider that it is open it is considered as the last open and it should not expect the file is closed

**Thank you** in advance

Comment: I doubt that's possible. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: I need to access at the current open file or latest opened file. i can't imagine there is no way to do that !

Comment: Why is it so difficult for you to believe that? It would be weird if you just could do that on Android.

Comment: why it would be weird ?

Comment: Because you can't just access data of other apps, if an app wants to share data it has to provide an interface for that, either with `Intents` or maybe a `ContentProvider` or whatever. Wanting to know which file is open in another app is like wanting to know which color the `TextView` in another app has.

Comment: no i don't wan't know if this file is open on this app. i just want to know if this file is currently open or was open recently. i don't care about wich app opens this files i just want to know the path of this file, i just can't believe i can't know locked files quickly

Comment: Yeah well same thing, you could detect changes to files in a specific folder, or maybe read the file meta information to find out when a specific file was edited the last time, but that's it. You cannot get more information than that. And more importantly you cannot find out who made those modifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57237/discussion-between-colombet-josselyn-and-xaver-kapeller).